# Running JUnit only on tests impacted after classes modification

Tags: junit

Imagine you have a large project, with several thousands of JUnit tests.
Let's says that running all thoses tests takes 7 minutes.
This looks short when you build your project from an ant/maven script.

But when you are using Eclipse, you cannot run all your test very often, because 7 minutes is too long time.

So here is the question:
**When you modify some classes, is there a way to let JUnit runs only tests that *may* have been impacted by thoses class changes ?**

I mean, this sounds feasible using classloader feature : after running each test, it's possible to know which classes have been loaded for this test, and to store somewhere (even in memory) a signature of each class used for this test.

When Junit is launched again, it could, for each test, check if classes used by this test have been modified since the very last run, and then NOT launch the test if it was ok and if no class impacting the test has been changed. (If the test were OK for the last run, it should be OK)

Does someone know if this has been done/implemented already ?

Answer (score 1):

You could try using [**Infinitest**](http://infinitest.github.com/) from either Eclipse or IntelliJ. (Edited spelling)